# How can I make a group optional in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, url, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace:
`*facebook.com/`
with `http://graph.facebook.com/`

I need to be able to group anything before the `facebook.com` part into an optional group.

I can't just replace `facebook.com` with `graph.facebook.com` because the incoming URL may contain `https`.

Here's what I have but misses anything that doesn't have `http[s]://`.

```
<?php
$fb_url = preg_replace('/http[s]*:\/\/[www.]*facebook.com\//', 'http://graph.facebook.com/', 'facebook.com/some/segments');
echo $fb_url;
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing your question specifically:
You can make any single character (or a group of characters) optional by adding a `?` after it in your regex.

A couple of tips from looking at your code:

- If you are matching strings containing `/` characters, simplify your life by using a different delimiter (for example `#`). You aren't required to use a forward slash.
- You should escape the `.` dot metacharacter because it matches ANY single character, so your expression `www.` could conceivably match *www9* or anything else along those lines
- Also, the brackets `[...]` are for matching a range of characters. If you want to match specifically the text *www.* you should use a non-captured group like `(?:www\.)` and make it optional by adding the `?` after it like `(?:www\.)?`

---

So, those tips in mind, try ...

```
<?php

$p = '#(?:https?://(?:www\.)?)?facebook\.com/#';
$r = 'http://graph.facebook.com/';
$subject = 'facebook.com/some/segments';

$fb_url = preg_replace($p, $r, $subject);
echo $fb_url; // outputs: http://graph.facebook.com/some/segments

?>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the tips! Definitely did not know `#` could be used as a delimiter.

Answer (score 5):

use something like below

```
(optional-regex-here)?
```